# Как победить исключение SqlParameter уже содержится в другом SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

```
 public virtual PagerResult<ProdImgList> GetPagerRezFromStorProc(LineJsonModel model)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.QueryString))
        {
            model.QueryString = "";
        }
        else
        {
            model.QueryString = model.QueryString.Trim();
        }

        SqlParameter par1 = new SqlParameter("@par", "");
        SqlParameter par2 = new SqlParameter("@par", "cnt");
        SqlParameter par3 = new SqlParameter("@par", "price");
        SqlParameter par4 = new SqlParameter("@par", "listId");
        SqlParameter queryString = new SqlParameter("@query", model.QueryString);
        SqlParameter pageNo = new SqlParameter("@pageNo", model.PageNumber);
        SqlParameter pageSize = new SqlParameter("@pageSize", model.PageProductCount);
        SqlParameter sortPrice = new SqlParameter("@sortPrice", model.UpPriceOrder);
        SqlParameter sortRel = new SqlParameter("@sortRel", model.DownRankOrder);

        SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter("@Id", model.id);

        SqlParameter price_min = new SqlParameter("@price_min", model.MinPrice);
        SqlParameter price_max = new SqlParameter("@price_max", model.MaxPrice);

        SqlParameter nalichie = new SqlParameter("@nalichie", model.Nalichie);

        ///////////////////////***Категории***/////////////////////////////
        var listCatId = new DataTable();
        listCatId.TableName = "dbo.ListCatId";
        listCatId.Columns.Add("CatId", typeof(int));
        if (model.ListCatId != null && model.ListCatId.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.ListCatId.Distinct())
            {
                listCatId.Rows.Add(item); // Id of '1' is valid for the Person table
            }
        }

        SqlParameter catArray = new SqlParameter("CatIdArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        catArray.TypeName = listCatId.TableName;
        catArray.Value = listCatId;

        ////////////////////***Материалы***////////////////////////////////


        var selectTable1 = new DataTable();
        selectTable1.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable1.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Materials != null && model.Materials.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < model.Materials.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Materials[i] });
            }
        }

        SqlParameter materialArray = new SqlParameter("MaterialArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        materialArray.TypeName = selectTable1.TableName;
        materialArray.Value = selectTable1;

        ////////////////////***Нанесение***////////////////////////////////



        var selectTable2 = new DataTable();
        selectTable2.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable2.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Nanesenie != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Nanesenie.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable2.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Nanesenie[i] });
            }
        }
        SqlParameter nanesenieArray = new SqlParameter("NanesenieArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        nanesenieArray.TypeName = selectTable2.TableName;
        nanesenieArray.Value = selectTable2;

        ////////////////////***Бренд***////////////////////////////////



        var selectTable3 = new DataTable();
        selectTable3.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable3.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable3.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Brand != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Brand.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable3.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Brand[i] });
            }
        }
        SqlParameter brandArray = new SqlParameter("BrandArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        brandArray.TypeName = selectTable3.TableName;
        brandArray.Value = selectTable3;

        ////////////////////***Цвет***////////////////////////////////



        var selectTable4 = new DataTable();
        selectTable4.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable4.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable4.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Color != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Color.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable4.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Color[i] });
            }
        }
        SqlParameter colorArray = new SqlParameter("ColorArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        colorArray.TypeName = selectTable4.TableName;
        colorArray.Value = selectTable4;

        List<Products> prodList;

        prodList = db.Database.SqlQuery<Products>(@"exec FullTextSaerchInProducts @par, @query,@pageNo,@pageSize,@sortPrice,@sortRel,
            @Id,@price_min,@price_max,@nalichie,@CatIdArray,@MaterialArray,@NanesenieArray,@BrandArray,@ColorArray",
            par1, queryString, pageNo, pageSize, sortPrice, sortRel, Id, price_min, price_max, nalichie, catArray,
            materialArray, nanesenieArray, brandArray, colorArray).ToList();

        PagerResult<ProdImgList> rezult = new PagerResult<ProdImgList>();

        rezult.Items = prodList.Join(db.ProdImages.Where(x => x.Main == true), prod => prod.Id, imag => imag.ProdId, (prod, imag) =>
                     new ProdImgList { ProdId = prod.Id, ImagePath = imag.Big, Product = prod }).ToList();

        rezult.TotalCount = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"exec FullTextSaerchInProducts @par, @query,@pageNo,@pageSize,@sortPrice,@sortRel,
            @Id,@price_min,@price_max,@nalichie,@CatIdArray,@MaterialArray,@NanesenieArray,@BrandArray,@ColorArray",
            par1, queryString, pageNo, pageSize, sortPrice, sortRel, Id, price_min, price_max, nalichie, catArray,
            materialArray, nanesenieArray, brandArray, colorArray);



        List<PriceModel> prices = db.Database.SqlQuery<PriceModel>(@"exec FullTextSaerchInProducts @par, @query,@pageNo,@pageSize,@sortPrice,@sortRel,
            @Id,@price_min,@price_max,@nalichie,@CatIdArray,@MaterialArray,@NanesenieArray,@BrandArray,@ColorArray",
            par1, queryString, pageNo, pageSize, sortPrice, sortRel, Id, price_min, price_max, nalichie, catArray,
            materialArray, nanesenieArray, brandArray, colorArray).ToList();

        rezult.minPrice = prices.FirstOrDefault().minPriceCat;
        rezult.maxPrice = prices.FirstOrDefault().maxPriceCat;

        return rezult;
    }
```

В коде выше(метод в приложении asp.net mvc 6, ef6, sql server 2012, ) при выполнении второго вызова процедуры происходит исключение. Но бред переписывать каждый раз эту тираду параметров. Как красиво победить?

Переписал следующим образом код, но опять та же самая ошибка.

```
public virtual PagerResult<ProdImgList> GetPagerRezFromStorProc(LineJsonModel model)
    {

       List<SqlParameter> lstTableParam1= CreateParameters(model);
        SqlParameter par1 = lstTableParam1[0];
        SqlParameter par2 = lstTableParam1[1];
        SqlParameter par3 = lstTableParam1[2];
        SqlParameter par4 = lstTableParam1[3];
        SqlParameter queryString = lstTableParam1[4];
        SqlParameter pageNo = lstTableParam1[5];
        SqlParameter pageSize = lstTableParam1[6];
        SqlParameter sortPrice = lstTableParam1[7];
        SqlParameter sortRel = lstTableParam1[8];
        SqlParameter Id = lstTableParam1[9];
        SqlParameter price_min = lstTableParam1[10];
        SqlParameter price_max = lstTableParam1[11];
        SqlParameter nalichie = lstTableParam1[12];
        SqlParameter catArray1 = lstTableParam1[13];
        SqlParameter materialArray1 = lstTableParam1[14];
        SqlParameter nanesenieArray1 = lstTableParam1[15];
        SqlParameter brandArray1 = lstTableParam1[16];
        SqlParameter colorArray1 = lstTableParam1[17];


        List<Products> prodList;

        prodList = db.Database.SqlQuery<Products>(@"exec FullTextSaerchInProducts @par, @query,@pageNo,@pageSize,@sortPrice,@sortRel,
            @Id,@price_min,@price_max,@nalichie,@CatIdArray,@MaterialArray,@NanesenieArray,@BrandArray,@ColorArray",
            par1, queryString, pageNo, pageSize, sortPrice, sortRel, Id, price_min, price_max, nalichie, catArray1,
            materialArray1, nanesenieArray1, brandArray1, colorArray1).ToList();

        PagerResult<ProdImgList> rezult = new PagerResult<ProdImgList>();

        rezult.Items = prodList.Join(db.ProdImages.Where(x => x.Main == true), prod => prod.Id, imag => imag.ProdId, (prod, imag) =>
                     new ProdImgList { ProdId = prod.Id, ImagePath = imag.Big, Product = prod }).ToList();



        //rezult.TotalCount = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"exec FullTextSaerchInProducts @par, @query,@pageNo,@pageSize,@sortPrice,@sortRel,
        //    @Id,@price_min,@price_max,@nalichie,@CatIdArray,@MaterialArray,@NanesenieArray,@BrandArray,@ColorArray",
        //    par1, queryString, pageNo, pageSize, sortPrice, sortRel, Id, price_min, price_max, nalichie, catArray,
        //    materialArray, nanesenieArray, brandArray, colorArray);

        List<SqlParameter> lstTableParam2 = CreateParameters(model);
        SqlParameter par12 = lstTableParam1[0];
        SqlParameter par22 = lstTableParam1[1];
        SqlParameter par32 = lstTableParam1[2];
        SqlParameter par42 = lstTableParam1[3];
        SqlParameter queryString2 = lstTableParam1[4];
        SqlParameter pageNo2 = lstTableParam1[5];
        SqlParameter pageSize2= lstTableParam1[6];
        SqlParameter sortPrice2 = lstTableParam1[7];
        SqlParameter sortRel2 = lstTableParam1[8];
        SqlParameter Id2 = lstTableParam1[9];
        SqlParameter price_min2 = lstTableParam1[10];
        SqlParameter price_max2 = lstTableParam1[11];
        SqlParameter nalichie2 = lstTableParam1[12];
        SqlParameter catArray12 = lstTableParam1[13];
        SqlParameter materialArray12 = lstTableParam1[14];
        SqlParameter nanesenieArray12 = lstTableParam1[15];
        SqlParameter brandArray12 = lstTableParam1[16];
        SqlParameter colorArray12 = lstTableParam1[17];


        List<PriceModel> prices = db.Database.SqlQuery<PriceModel>(@"exec FullTextSaerchInProducts @par, @query,@pageNo,@pageSize,@sortPrice,@sortRel,
            @Id,@price_min,@price_max,@nalichie,@CatIdArray,@MaterialArray,@NanesenieArray,@BrandArray,@ColorArray",
            par32, queryString2, pageNo2, pageSize2, sortPrice2, sortRel2, Id2, price_min2, price_max2, nalichie2, catArray12,
            materialArray12, nanesenieArray12, brandArray12, colorArray12).ToList();

        rezult.minPrice = prices.FirstOrDefault().minPriceCat;
        rezult.maxPrice = prices.FirstOrDefault().maxPriceCat;

        return rezult;
    }


    private List<SqlParameter> CreateParameters(LineJsonModel model)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> listPrm = new List<SqlParameter>();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.QueryString))
        {
            model.QueryString = "";
        }
        else
        {
            model.QueryString = model.QueryString.Trim();
        }

        SqlParameter par1 = new SqlParameter("@par", "");
        SqlParameter par2 = new SqlParameter("@par", "cnt");
        SqlParameter par3 = new SqlParameter("@par", "price");
        SqlParameter par4 = new SqlParameter("@par", "listId");
        SqlParameter queryString = new SqlParameter("@query", model.QueryString);
        SqlParameter pageNo = new SqlParameter("@pageNo", model.PageNumber);
        SqlParameter pageSize = new SqlParameter("@pageSize", model.PageProductCount);
        SqlParameter sortPrice = new SqlParameter("@sortPrice", model.UpPriceOrder);
        SqlParameter sortRel = new SqlParameter("@sortRel", model.DownRankOrder);

        SqlParameter Id = new SqlParameter("@Id", model.id);

        SqlParameter price_min = new SqlParameter("@price_min", model.MinPrice);
        SqlParameter price_max = new SqlParameter("@price_max", model.MaxPrice);

        SqlParameter nalichie = new SqlParameter("@nalichie", model.Nalichie);

        ///////////////////////***Категории***/////////////////////////////
        var listCatId = new DataTable();
        listCatId.TableName = "dbo.ListCatId";
        listCatId.Columns.Add("CatId", typeof(int));
        if (model.ListCatId != null && model.ListCatId.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.ListCatId.Distinct())
            {
                listCatId.Rows.Add(item); // Id of '1' is valid for the Person table
            }
        }

        SqlParameter catArray = new SqlParameter("CatIdArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        catArray.TypeName = listCatId.TableName;
        catArray.Value = listCatId;

        ////////////////////***Материалы***////////////////////////////////


        var selectTable1 = new DataTable();
        selectTable1.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable1.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Materials != null && model.Materials.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < model.Materials.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable1.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Materials[i] });
            }
        }

        SqlParameter materialArray = new SqlParameter("MaterialArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        materialArray.TypeName = selectTable1.TableName;
        materialArray.Value = selectTable1;

        ////////////////////***Нанесение***////////////////////////////////



        var selectTable2 = new DataTable();
        selectTable2.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable2.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Nanesenie != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Nanesenie.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable2.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Nanesenie[i] });
            }
        }
        SqlParameter nanesenieArray = new SqlParameter("NanesenieArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        nanesenieArray.TypeName = selectTable2.TableName;
        nanesenieArray.Value = selectTable2;

        ////////////////////***Бренд***////////////////////////////////



        var selectTable3 = new DataTable();
        selectTable3.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable3.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable3.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Brand != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Brand.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable3.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Brand[i] });
            }
        }
        SqlParameter brandArray = new SqlParameter("BrandArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        brandArray.TypeName = selectTable3.TableName;
        brandArray.Value = selectTable3;

        ////////////////////***Цвет***////////////////////////////////



        var selectTable4 = new DataTable();
        selectTable4.TableName = "dbo.SelectList";
        selectTable4.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        selectTable4.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        if (model.Color != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Color.Count; i++)
            {
                selectTable4.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, model.Color[i] });
            }
        }
        SqlParameter colorArray = new SqlParameter("ColorArray", SqlDbType.Structured);
        colorArray.TypeName = selectTable4.TableName;
        colorArray.Value = selectTable4;

        listPrm.Add(par1);
        listPrm.Add(par2);
        listPrm.Add(par3);
        listPrm.Add(par4);
        listPrm.Add(queryString);
        listPrm.Add(pageNo);
        listPrm.Add(pageSize);
        listPrm.Add(sortPrice);
        listPrm.Add(sortRel);
        listPrm.Add(Id);
        listPrm.Add(price_min);
        listPrm.Add(price_max);
        listPrm.Add(nalichie);
        listPrm.Add(catArray);
        listPrm.Add(materialArray);
        listPrm.Add(nanesenieArray);
        listPrm.Add(brandArray);
        listPrm.Add(colorArray);

        return listPrm;

    }
```

Comment: Вынесите создание всех `SqlParameter` в отдельный метод. И вызывайте этот метод перед каждым вызовом процедуры.

Comment: то же самое. Какой то кошмар.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, почему минус? Я Гуглю уже со вчерашнего дня и не могу понять в чем проблема. Я переписал метд и вынес формирование параметров в отдельный метод, но это не помогает.

Comment: у вас имеется несколько параметров с одинаковым названием @par.

Comment: Alexcei Shmakov,Я закоментировал, те, которые не планировал использовать, и опять то же исключение на втором заходе выполнения процедуры.Кроме того, в вызове процедуры используется только один параметр соответствующий.

Comment: В обоих случаях значения берутся из `lstTableParam1` (исправьте 1 на 2 после второго вызова).

Comment: Alexander Petrov ДА!!!! СПАСИБО!!!!